# Animation doesnt work for all views (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I've got a few components which I need to animate. I've been using `UIVIew.animate()` for a long time with no issues. However in this case, one of the components doesnt animate (specifically `pullUpViewBottomCSTR`) , it simply "jumps" the view into place with no animation ( while the rest work as expected ).

Can you offer any possible explanations for this (as it would probably be spammy to copy paste everything). I'm very confused.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.pullUpViewBottomCSTR!.constant = 0
            self.mainImagePullUpBottomCSTR.constant = 0

            self.obscuringFadeEffectView.alpha = 0;

            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { (completed) in
            //
        }
```

1. I don't think I've got any conflicting constraints in place.
2. This code resides in a `UIView` component, not a `UIViewController`.
3. Im loading this component inside a viewController. I used to have the whole thing inside the UIViewController and i think it used to work properly until i moved it to its corresponding .xib and .swift files.

Update:

The constraint is originally added as follows. ( this might be relevant )

```
   self.pullUpViewBottomCSTR =  parentController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
   self.pullUpViewBottomCSTR!.isActive = true;
   self.pullUpViewBottomCSTR!.constant = 0
```

I am later using a pan recogniser and update the constraint as needed ( and this is why im keeping a reference to it ).

Comment: try to write self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: The current component is a UIView, not a UIViewController

i've attempted to do the following : self.pullupView.layoutIfNeeded(). Doesnt seem to work. And i would expect i wouldnt have to do that as im already doing self.layoutIfNeeded() on the superview. But in any case its unfortunately not changing anything : /

Comment: Check the constraint's initial value (should other then 0)

Comment: Yeah, its got an initial value. Its -400, its hidden and i display it by setting it to 0. This normally works.

Comment: why this constraint requires `!`?

Comment: no reason. just messy code right now. cleanup will follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view you are tying to animate is `self` but its vertical position is controlled by this constraint:

```
self.pullUpViewBottomCSTR = parentController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
```

When you activate this constraint with:

```
self.pullUpViewBottomCSTR!.isActive = true
```

it gets added to the constraints for the earliest common ancestor of `self` and `parentController.view` (which may be one of those views if one is a direct descendant of the other).  In order to animate that constraint, you need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` on that earliest common ancestor.

You haven't shown how the view represented by `self` is related to `parentController.view`, but assuming it is a `subview` of that view, then you can animate it with:

```
self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
```

inside of the animation loop.

Alternatively:

```
parentController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

should work as well.

Comment: This worked. I am very eager to learn why it is the case. The animation happens inside the UIView itself so all the subviews involved in it are contained inside. Why does the superview ( in this case a UIViewController ) need to be invoked?

Thank you so much for taking the time, i would be very grateful if you could point me to the right directions so that i can understand why it is i am doing what am i doing here.

Thanks again.

Comment: I've reworked the answer to give a better explanation.